# How to show div elements after hover and keep them visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

it's possible to hide div elements and show them if I hover the "strong" tag? Now, I have in the fieldset about 50 divs and the filter is too long. I want to show the divs after hover it and keep it. It's possible?

I don't have the permission to change the code (I can only use JS and styles which I can add to  or .

Thanks :-)

```
<div class="param-filter-single">
   <form method="post">
      <fieldset class="parametric-filter">
         <strong>CATEGORY</strong>
         <br>
         <div class="param-filter-single-cell large-3 medium-4 small-6">content</div>
         <div class="param-filter-single-cell large-3 medium-4 small-6">content</div>
         <div class="param-filter-single-cell large-3 medium-4 small-6">content</div>
      </fieldset>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you tried to google it before posting?

Comment: I found some solutions there but it doesn't work because the divs aren't the child elements of strong tag.

Comment: @Patrik The divs don't need to be the child elements of the strong tag.... This is jQuery, you can target any element in the DOM

Comment: @Patrick you can use jQuery or only plain JS?

Comment: @August Of course :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target your `strong` element directly and use it to show and hide your divs on hover. Best to add a class to the `strong` element, but if you can't you can do it like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/27bu03x5/15/

**HTML**

```
<div class="param-filter-single">
   <form method="post">
      <fieldset class="parametric-filter">
         <strong>CATEGORY</strong>
         <br>
         <div class="param-filter-single-cell large-3 medium-4 small-6">content</div>
         <div class="param-filter-single-cell large-3 medium-4 small-6">content</div>
         <div class="param-filter-single-cell large-3 medium-4 small-6">content</div>
      </fieldset>
   </form>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var container = $(".parametric-filter").first();
var divs = container.find($(".param-filter-single-cell"));
var trigger = $("strong").first();

divs.hide();
trigger.hover(function(){
    divs.show();
});
```

Comment: @user1515791 Does the question mention multiple fieldsets?

Comment: Yeah, this works and I have this before but I have more "param-filter-single" because of more CATEGORIES and this function will show all of them, not just the one I am hovering. I should write it before. It's possible to do it if the div class have same name? :-)

But thank's anyway.

Comment: @Patrik You can target the `param-single-filter` elements more directly. I updated the answer accordingly. You can not add classes to the HTML?

Comment: @A Tom Called Stu

Hm, not working, maybe we don't understand each other.

I have more "param-filter-single" divs, and if I use this function, it opens all of them.

See there on the left, just click on "Filtr podle parametrů, vlastností a výrobců" [link]https://222912.myshoptet.com/granule-pro-dospele-psy/

Comment: @Patrik I understand your problem. I'm sure you can understand why this is happening by looking at the code. Can you add classes to the existing HTML elements?

Comment: @A Tom Called Stu

Don't think so, maybe using JS? In admin page I can't.

Comment: I just try to figure out. It's possible to use "parametric-filter:first-child", "parametric-filter + parametric-filter" etc.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173770/discussion-between-patrik-and-a-tom-called-stu).

Answer (score 0):

Pure js and support for multiple groups:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfqdm3p7/8/)

```
var tohide = document.getElementsByClassName('param-filter-single-cell');
for(var i =0 ; i< tohide.length; i++){
     tohide[i].style.display = 'none';
 }
 var handles = document.getElementsByTagName('strong');

 for(var i = 0 ; i< handles.length; i++){
      handles[i].onmouseover = function(e){
      var toshow = e.currentTarget.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('param-filter-single-cell');
      for(var i =0 ; i< toshow.length; i++){
      toshow[i].style.display = 'block';
 }};}
```

Comment: This does nothing :-(

Comment: ... Yeah it does :) have you looked at the fiddle? If it does not work for your page, then something else in there is interfering. Sec with the code you posted, it does exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(".parametric-filter").mouseover(function(){
    $('.param-filter-single-cell').slideDown();
});
```

```css
.param-filter-single-cell { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="param-filter-single">
   <form method="post">
      <fieldset class="parametric-filter">
         <strong>CATEGORY</strong>
         <br>
         <div class="param-filter-single-cell large-3 medium-4 small-6">content</div>
         <div class="param-filter-single-cell large-3 medium-4 small-6">content</div>
         <div class="param-filter-single-cell large-3 medium-4 small-6">content</div>
      </fieldset>
   </form>
</div>
```

Solution using jquery:

```
$("strong").mouseover(function(){
    $('.param-filter-single-cell').show();
});
```

Or using slide:

```
$("strong").mouseover(function(){
    $('.param-filter-single-cell').slideDown();
});
```

Javascript:

```
strongEl = document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[0];
childElements = document.getElementsByClassName("param-filter-single-cell");
strongEl.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    childElements.style.display = "block"
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
.param-filter-single-cell{
  display:none;
}

.parametric-filter:hover .param-filter-single-cell{
  display:block
}
```

```html
    <div class="param-filter-single">
       <form method="post">
          <fieldset class="parametric-filter">
             <strong>CATEGORY</strong>
             <br>
             <div class="param-filter-single-cell large-3 medium-4 small-6">content</div>
             <div class="param-filter-single-cell large-3 medium-4 small-6">content</div>
             <div class="param-filter-single-cell large-3 medium-4 small-6">content</div>
          </fieldset>
       </form>
    </div>
```

Like this?